# How to pass two parameters or arguments in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am new to bash scripting and I need your support to solve this problem. I have a bash script "start.sh". I want to write a script with two arguments so that I could run the script in the following way

./start.sh -dayoffset 1 -processMode true

dayoffset and processMode are the two parameters that I have to script.

dayoffset = 1 is the reporting date (today)
processMode = true or false

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a start you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dayoffset=$1
processMode=$2
echo "Do something with $dayoffset and $processMode."
```

Usage:

```
./start.sh 1 true
```

Another:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -dayoffset)
        day_offset=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -processMode)
        if [[ $2 != true && $2 != false ]]; then
            echo "Option argument to '-processMode' can only be 'true' or 'false'."
            exit 1
        fi
        process_mode=$2
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid argument: $1"
        exit 1
    esac
    shift
done

echo "Do something with $day_offset and $process_mode."
```

Usage:

```
./start.sh -dayoffset 1 -processMode true
```

Example argument parsing with day offset:

```
#!/bin/bash 
dayoffset=$1
date -d "now + $dayoffset days"
```

Test:

```
$ bash script.sh 0
Fri Aug 15 09:44:42 UTC 2014
$ bash script.sh 5
Wed Aug 20 09:44:43 UTC 2014
```

Comment: Hi, thanks of the reply. My script is more or less like this. Does it make any sense. `code`
if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                DAY_OFFSET="-1"
        else
                DAY_OFFSET="$1"
        fi
        if [ -n "$2" ] && [ $2 = "repeat" ]; then
                echo "Wiederholungslauf"
                PARAMETERS="${PARAMETERS} -processMode true"
        else
                echo "Default"
                PARAMETERS="${PARAMETERS} -processMode false"

        fi
   else
        echo "Wrong count of paramaeters given"
         batch_exit
fi
`code`

Comment: @user1983063 Your version is not too dynamic. I suggest you use the general form I gave. I actually prefer all-caps variable names so can you just change those variables to all-caps forms. Just be careful on using builtin shell variables.... And you're welcome :)